# using SQLMAP to test SQL injection in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, testing, code-injection, web-testing, sqlmap

I am trying to get SQLMAP tool to test the possibilities of SQL injection on my asp.net web application which has forms authentication. But I am not getting any clear directions on this. I have tried my hands on numerous forums and found nothing concrete for ASP.NET web application. Most of the demos are provided for PHP sites, which does not work like ASP.NET.

When I try to run

```
sqlmap.py -u "https://test.XXXX_SIT/login.aspx" --dbs
```

command, I end up getting the below response from the SQLMAP console

[image: Response from SQLMAP]

I am new to this aspect of security testing and I am even open for any better and simple **free** tool that does the job for me.

Please let me know the possible solution or other better possibilities to achieve this.

Regards,

Krishna Samaga B.

Comment: Are you sending any POST data ?

Answer (score 0):

You need parameters to test.

```
sqlmap.py -u "https://test.XXXX_SIT/login.aspx?login=1&pass=2" --dbs
```

for example login and pass are `GET` parameters.

or

```
sqlmap.py -u "https://test.XXXX_SIT/login.aspx" --data='login=1&pass=2' --dbs
```

if you're sending `POST` request with login and pass